# Testing application exception handling from UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, testing, exception

I have an application that is in the process of implementing the one transaction per business conversation pattern. This way if anything goes wrong when persisting entities we can rollback the entire transaction and not be left with entities in an inconsistent state.

I realize that I can unit test this to ensure that transactions are being rollbacked using mocks. What I'm looking for is how can I test this by actually being a user of the application.

I've toyed with the idea of creating a simple application that could break my schema by renaming columns or even modifying column lengths. This way any attempt to save entities to the table I modified would throw an exception. While it appears to be working, I'm not convinced this is the way to go.

I'm struggling with figuring out how to proceed that I'm properly handling server generated exceptions, such as `TimeoutException`.

Comment: To test a `TimeoutException`, just unplug your internet cable.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot do this as we often test in virtual environments that we connect through RDP. My bad solution at the time was to disable the NIC from my RDP session. I won't go into detail as to what happened. :P